# Servicestack - Google authentication error

Tags: servicestack, google-oauth

I'm getting the following error when when trying to make login with a google account in production environment:

```
2017-02-06 10:34:26.8978|DEBUG|HttpResponseExtensionsInternal|Setting Custom HTTP Header: Accept-Ranges: bytes
2017-02-06 10:34:26.8978|DEBUG|HttpResponseExtensionsInternal|Setting Custom HTTP Header: Location: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fproductionurl.com%2Fapi%2Fauth%2FGoogleOAuth&state=xxxxxxxx&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&response_type=code
2017-02-06 10:34:26.8978|DEBUG|HttpResponseExtensionsInternal|Setting Custom HTTP Header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
2017-02-06 10:34:26.8978|DEBUG|HttpResponseExtensionsInternal|Setting Custom HTTP Header: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
2017-02-06 10:34:26.8978|DEBUG|HttpResponseExtensionsInternal|Setting Custom HTTP Header: Pragma: no-cache
2017-02-06 10:34:38.3492|WARN|StringMapTypeDeserializer|Property 'code' does not exist on type 'ServiceStack.Authenticate'
2017-02-06 10:34:38.3492|DEBUG|RedisNativeClient|S: GET urn:iauthsession:tWsIDUa1jLZAXzXYK8Ob
2017-02-06 10:34:38.3492|DEBUG|RedisNativeClient|R: $510
2017-02-06 10:34:39.0678|ERROR|AppHost|DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
  at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, DirectWebRequestOptions options)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, DirectWebRequestOptions options)
  at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.RequestCore(IDirectedProtocolMessage request)
  at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Request(IDirectedProtocolMessage requestMessage)
  at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ClientBase.UpdateAuthorizationWithResponse(IAuthorizationState authorizationState, EndUserAuthorizationSuccessAuthCodeResponse authorizationSuccess)
  at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.WebServerClient.ProcessUserAuthorization(HttpRequestBase request)
    at ServiceStack.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Provider.Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Authenticate request)
  at ServiceStack.Auth.AuthenticateService.Authenticate(Authenticate request, String provider, IAuthSession session, IAuthProvider oAuthConfig)
  at ServiceStack.Auth.AuthenticateService.Post(Authenticate request)
  at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object )
  at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequest request, Object instance, TRequest requestDto)
2017-02-06 10:34:39.0990|ERROR|ServiceStackHost|ServiceBase<TRequest>::Service Exception
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
  at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, DirectWebRequestOptions options)
```

Facebook authentication works perfect in production. In development both google and facebook authentication work well but in production I'm getting this error only for google authentication.

Apparently Google authentication is done correctly, in the browser inspector in the network tab I can see the following redirect:

https://productionurl.com/api/auth/GoogleOAuth?state=XXXXLiO-LQf6EoGYMw&code=XXXXXwduRVs96RIBCdkao2nQDgKDFvvQhT8

But something go wrong in the last authentication step.

The production environment is behind a load balancer. Could the balancer be the problem?

Is there way to dig more deeply to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since GoogleOAuth uses DotNetOpenAuth you can [setup your Web Application to use Glimpse](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HttpBenchmarks#setting-up-glimpse) to get more detailed logging around OAuth issues.